# GNOME classic minimizer tweak/similar desktop enviorment

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, taskbar, openbox, xmonad

I've been using the GNOME classic desktop environment for Ubuntu 12.04 for a while now, and after installing conky, I've realized that the taskbars make it look cluttered. Are there any tweaking programs that can hide/remove/change the top or bottom taskbar, or a different desktop enviorment overall?

I've tried openbox and XMonad, but I could never configure it right, so a more easily-configured environment would be nice, or just the GNOME manipulator.

(NOTE: I've tried gnome-tweak, not extensive enough)

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>click 3</kbd> (right click) on a **panel** will offer a menu with :

- new panel
- remove this panel
- add objects to this panel
- properties

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>click 3</kbd> on an **object** will offer a menu with :

- move the object on the panel or to another panel
- remove it

<kbd>click 3</kbd> on the **objects** will give you their preferences.

If you create a new panel you can add the `unity panel` area 
[image: unity panel area] just add `indicator applet complete`

[image: indicator applet complete]

Have fun :D